# Using hardware PWM and audio at the same time

Tags: audio, pwm

While using PWM0 and PWM1, sound (buzz) is played through the audiojack.

Is it possible to route audio not through PWM so it could be used at the same time as PWM?

Comment: If you absolutely have to have audio and PWM at the same time your best bet is likely either a USB sound card or an HDMI to VGA converter with a 3.5mm audio out. Both are cheap and generally easy to set up.

Comment: @goobering Seems like a good idea, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The audio jack is driven by the hardware PWM peripheral.

You can use the hardware PWM peripheral to drive one or two channels (left and right) of audio or to drive one or two channels of PWM.

The choice is yours.